# How to get a list of all open NSWindow from all running application?

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Is there a way to get list of open or visible NSWindow from mac desktop?

Comment: Here is how to get running window informations in macOS https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/243

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that not all windows are necessarily `NSWindows`, and that `NSWindow` only provides an interface to windows in your own address space.

The supported way to access every window is the `CGWindow` API. Take a look at the [Son of Grab](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code to see how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the Son of Grab link, most helpful.

Comment: I searched like 2 hours for this!

Comment: Why not all windows are necessarily NSWindows? Then what are those cgwindows super class?
Could you give me a reference to look it up?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the accessibility API (accessibility must be enabled under System Preferences for it to work) to get information on windows (and other UI elements) from other processes. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107657/mac-cocoa-getting-a-list-of-windows-using-accessibility-api) might be just what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**ALL** running applications?  No.  You can only get the NSWindows of your own app.  You may be able to use Universal Access or Core Graphics APIs to get some information about windows of other apps, but not full access.

Comment: To get the `NSWindow`s of your own app, you can use `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] windows]` (in case anyone is looking for such a thing, and stumbled on this question)