# Get all windows in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to get all opened non qt window from qt application and display them , i get all opened window but i can't display their names or positions.

```
this->_WindowsList = QGuiApplication::allWindows(); // i get all windows

 for (uint i = 0 ; i< _WindowsList.size() ; i++)
    {
        this->ui->listWidget->addItem(_WindowsList.at(i)->title()); // no name are displayed just rows 

    }
```

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Read more about [EWMH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints)...

Comment: `QGuiApplication::allWindows` returns all the windows belonging to the application, not all the toplevel windows in the system. As of Qt 5.2, there's no Qt method for doing that.

Comment: Is there any solution to make it (cross platform solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "universal Qt way" of enumerating all the active windows opened in your environment. There are different ways of doing this on different platforms/environments - your best bet is detecting the host operating system via `QSysInfo()` and then using OS specific code.

Here are some basic examples:

- Enumerating windows on systems with X11 [using xlib](http://static.cray-cyber.org/Documentation/NEC_SX_R10_1/G1AE02E/CHAP4.HTML)
- Using `EnumWindows()` on Microsoft Windows via the [WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- I didn't really find a clear cut way of doing this on Mac OS X, but [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036420/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-open-nswindow-from-all-running-application) should be able to help point you in the right direction.

Comment: QT != Qt, Also, please try to eliminate the external links when possible with inline content.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Fixed the QT vs Qt issue, sorry about that. As for the formatting - what do you recommend I do? I just wanted to provide as much information as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I would personally collect the main points of the external knowledge into your answer. Also, please remove things like "Cheers!" as well. :-)

Comment: You'll need to detect OS with compiler defines and `#ifdef` preprosessor directives... OS specific code usually does not even compile for wrong OS, so runtime mechanism like `QSysInfo` isn't possible.